# Async/ Await test using Jest Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

Trying to run a test for the following code using Jest and Enzyme. The code is actually passing but not affecting its coverage. Just wondering what i could add into in order to work properly and increase test coverage

here is the function :

```
async getCurrencies() {
  const { user, services } = this.props;
  let types = response.body ? response.body.value : null;
  let response = await DropdownModels.getCurrencies({ user, services })
  let temp = types.map((type) => {        
    return {
     label: type.Name,
     value: type.Currency1,
   }
  })
 this.setState({ CurrencyOptions: temp });
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
it ('Test getCurrencies function ',async() => {
 wrapper.setProps({
    user:{},
    serviceS:{},
  })
 wrapper.find('TransactionForm').setState({
    CurrencyOptions:[[]]
   });
 wrapper.update();
 await expect(wrapper.find('TransactionForm').instance().getCurrencies('test')).toBeDefined();
});
```

Also tried the following

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.find('TransactionForm').instance(), 'getCurrencies');
await expect(spy).toBeCalled()
```

But get the following error using spy :

```
   expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
   Expected mock function to have been called.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's start with the basic concepts of writing tests.

**What should I test?**

All the lines of code should be tested so that achieve as high coverage as possible - ~100% for sure. On the other hand, the percentage might be unreliable in some cases.

**Why should I deal with tests?**

Tests help determine whether the previous implementations are broken due to the new functionalities. You just have to "press the button" instead of verifying it manually.

There're many other concepts both at the basic and high level, but let's try to keep this list brief and jump back into the details of the issue.

---

To stick with your example above, let me leave some observations.

```js
it('Test getCurrencies function', async () => { ... });
```

This test description doesn't tell anything about the intention of this case. It tests the function, but how? What parts of the function does it cover? It's really difficult to answer these questions without specific details in the description.

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.find('TransactionForm').instance(), 'getCurrencies');
```

I'm not sure what `TransactionForm` is, but according to the [**official documentation**](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname), it accepts the following parameters:

```js
jest.spyOn(object, methodName)
```

Are you sure that `wrapper.find('TransactionForm').instance()` returns an object and also contains the `getCurrencies` function?

```js
let response = await DropdownModels.getCurrencies({ user, services });
```

It's pretty odd - and also confusing - that `DropdownModels` also has a `getCurrencies` method. This might not be a problem, but I'd rather consider renaming it.

---

Finally, here are some example test cases that might be a good starting point in your case:

```js
describe("getCurrencies", () => {
   it("calls `DropdownModels.getCurrencies` with `user` and `services` props", () => {
      // Don't forget to set the desired props as you did it in your samples.
      // Simply mock `DropdownModels.getCurrencies` with `jest.spyOn`.
   });

   it("sets `temp` into the state", () => {
      // Test whether the expected data is set into the state.
   });
});
```